# Extracting df.residual from a fixest object

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

How do I extract the degrees of freedom (`df.residual`) from a `fixest` object?

Other common packages directly report it in the output object and allow for its computation via `stats::df.residual()`:

```
glm_outp <- glm(vs ~ drat + mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
glm_outp$df.residual
[1] 29
df.residual(glm_outp)
[1] 29

felm_outp <- lfe::felm(vs ~ drat + mpg | gear, data = mtcars)
felm_outp$df.residual
[1] 27
df.residual(felm_outp)
[1] 27
```

That is not the case for `fixest`:

```
feglm_outp <- fixest::feglm(vs ~ drat + mpg | gear, data = mtcars, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
feglm_outp$df.residual
NULL
df.residual(feglm_outp)
NULL
summary(feglm_outp)$df.residual
NULL
```

The package allows to set degree of freedom options via `fixest::dof()` and `fixest::setFixest_dof()`. However, I want to extract the degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

`fitstat(feglm_outp ,'g')`

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for exactly that. Thanks. The bounty is still blocked for another 22 hours. I will award it tomorrow.